# Using Map and Filter at the same time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the map and filter example at:

[https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/map-filter#:~:text=JavaScript%27s%20Array%23map%20%28%29%20and%20Array%23filter%20%28%29%20functions%20are,function%20works%20fine%20on%20an%20array%20of%20numbers](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/map-filter#:%7E:text=JavaScript%27s%20Array%23map%20%28%29%20and%20Array%23filter%20%28%29%20functions%20are,function%20works%20fine%20on%20an%20array%20of%20numbers).

```
var data = [
        {
            "pmid": 12637528,           
            "citation_count": 75
        },
        {
            "pmid": 12732634,          
            "citation_count": 49
        },
        {
            "pmid": 15118089,           
            "citation_count": 88
        }
]
```

I am using

```
let iIndex =  data.map(d => d.citation_count).filter( d.citation_count >=50);
```

and

```
 let iIndex =  data.map(d => d.citation_count).filter( data.citation_count >=50);
```

but I get the following error:
"err = ReferenceError: d is not defined at eval"
or with data.citation
err = TypeError: false is not a function at Array.filter

If I take the .filter off it works fine, and I get an array of just the citation count.
Can someone help with the correct syntax for the filter portion?  I have searched stackOverflow but there are a lot of answers that are about 10 years old and I'm not sure what the most current direction has gone.  I have even seen a mention of flatMap.  Thanks for the help

Comment: You have to pass a **function** to `.filter()`

Comment: you are returning a number from map, so you will end up with an array of numbers, and not an array of objects

Comment: If you want to both filter and map simultaneously, `.reduce` is a better fit.

Comment: `data.map(d => d.citation_count).filter(d => d.citation_count >=50);`

Answer (score 3):

It's unnecessary to have  `d.citation_count` in filter:

```js
let iIndex =  data.map(d => d.citation_count).filter( d => d >=50);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is failing is because `filter` expects a function that returns a boolean - you have provided it with an expression.

A simple fix to your code would be to wrap your expression in an anonymous function:

```
const result = data.map(item => item.citation_count).filter(count => count >= 50)
```

You could also just use `reduce`, which combines the effect of both the `filter` and `map` functions, making the code more efficient:

```js
const data = [
    { pmid: 12637528, citation_count: 75 },
    { pmid: 12732634, citation_count: 49 },
    { pmid: 15118089, citation_count: 88 },
]

const result = data.reduce((result, { citation_count }) => {
  if (citation_count >= 50) {
    result.push(citation_count)
  }
  return result
}, [])

console.log(result)
```